# Could someone explain this CSS code?

Tags: css, css-float

```
#menu ul ul ul {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 100%; /* everything goes to opposite direction why?? It doesnt make sense */
width: 100%;
}
```

It's a simple dropDown in CSS (I'm learning CSS)... Have a look at the code where I'm hiding the blocks [here](http://jsbin.com/eyibes/7/edit) in JS Bin.

Comment: you want someone to explain the whole thing to you?

Comment: @YoniGeek asked the question within a comment in the code

Comment: @Ibu I just want to know why this line of code makes the thing to move to different direction...

Comment: `left` moves things from left to right. so left %100 will move your element 100% to the left

Comment: @ibu 100% to the right u mean! :) it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

your code:

```
left: 100%; /* everything goes to opposite direction why?? :( */
```

change to:

```
left: -100%;
```

Also, this works in Chrome. I noticed your menu code does not work in IE9.

Comment: no idea if this is a good answer or not, but point to you for trying.

Comment: @PengOne Yes I know this code doesnt work in IE but I still dont understand why this moves to different direction?? :)